# Change git account in specific project

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab

My BitBucket account is globally installed for my git projects.

Now I have to use my Gitlab account from school for a project. When I try to clone the repository I get the error:

```
Cloning into '*****'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the co
```

I think that it is because I try to clone with my BitBucket account which is not connected to this Gitlab repository.

Does someone know how I can change my config for only this project?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Are you cloning with SSH key? your clone url `git@...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in your `GitLab` account.

Go to `GitHub Profile` | `SSH Keys` | <kbd>`Add SSH Key`</kbd> using browser. Then add a new SSH key with `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

[Create and Add SSH key](https://youtu.be/54mxyLo3Mqk)

---

Alternate, Change your clone URL from `SSH` to `https`. Then clone the repo with your `GitLab username/password`.

Comment: Ah thanks! Creating a SSH key worked! With Bitbucket I always used the https url but that is disabled in this project.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to add your ssh key as @sajib khan suggested.

If you do not want to add your ssh key to gitlab, you can look and see if gitlab allows you to connect via http(s). If so then you can clone the repo with the http(s) link. If that is the case, then gitlab may ask you to login on occasion.

Comment: Https is disabled in this project! But adding a SSH worked! Thanks!